# Android LatinIME Dictionaries

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm creating my own input method app based on the **Android AOSP LatinIME** project. I managed to find some of the dictionary files for auto-correction and predictions **(main_en.dict, main_fr.dict etc.)**.

But for many other languages like `ru` and `ar`, the dictionary files are still missing. **Does anyone know where can I get those dict files?** Are they part of the `AOSP` project?(Is it legal to use them directly in my app)? Thanks a lot

Comment: And is there any document that describe the format or standard of the .dict files used by the google AOSP keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I'm investigating `LatinIME` too. It seems that you have to mimic the format of other dictionaries to create your own one, refer to `LatinIME/dictionaries`. After that, run `dicttool_aosp` to generate the binary dictionary, then put it into `resource/raw` folder.